# Regex for Active Directory Password policies

Tags: javascript, regex, active-directory

I need a Regex for Active Directory Password policy with the following conditions. 
My requirements are:

```
at least one digit (0-9)
at least one lowercase character
at least one uppercase character
must contain at least one special character and 
the length should be minimum 8 characters and maximum of 25
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this. its included with space bar validation.

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W]).{8,25})
```

Comment: That looks like a good one, I would replace `[\W]` with `[\W_]` in order for the underscore to be considered as a special character.